# Java/JVM: call native C method using it's address and signature

Tags: java, llvm, native

Let's say I have a C function

```
int32_t add(int32_t a, int32_t b) { return a + b; }
```

located at the address `long funcAddr` in my JVM process memory. Is there any way to call it from the Java code?

In python you can initialize a `CFUNCTYPE` instance from an integer. I'm looking for exactly the same functionality.

I found this [proposal](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~jrose/panama/native-call-primitive.html), but it doesn't seem to have been implemented in JVM.

My use case is that I generate a function using LLVM and want to execute it afterwards.

Comment: Out of curiosity: how do you get your method to be *located at the address long funcAddr in my JVM process memory*? Did you compile your own JVM?

Comment: The panama proposal that you linked to is ancient. There are early access builds of panama at http://jdk.java.net/panama/ (with links to more recent information). Otherwise, the usual way to call C functions is via JNI, which can be cumbersome. (There once was a section in the JNI book of how this could be generalized, now only archived e.g. at https://web.archive.org/web/20090130034722/http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/stubs.html , but admittedly, I never did dive into the details of that one...)

Comment: @GhostCat I'm using javacpp llvm bindings and `LLVMGetFunctionAddress`.

Comment: @Marco13 And probably all the new Graal stuff comes into play, too.

Comment: The tradional, standard, cumbersome way (as Marco13 says, and I agree) is through [JNI](https://www.baeldung.com/jni) (Java Native Interface), an alternative is by using [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) (Java Native Access) which should be easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

Following the advices in the comments, I used JNA 5.4.0 to invoke the function like this

```java
Function f = Function.getFunction(new Pointer(funcAddr), 0, "utf8");
long result = f.invoke(Long.class, long[]{1, 2});
// result == 3
```